# router link path in a navigation menu with angularJS2

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to create a navigation menu with angularJS2. This is what I have in `app.component.ts`:

```
 import {provide, Component} from 'angular2/core';
    import {APP_BASE_HREF, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy, RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
    import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
    import {Router} from 'angular2/router';


// Terrestri
@Component({
    selector: 'terrestri',
    template: '/terrestri.html', // WORKS
})
export class TerrestriComponent { }


// Volatili Component
@Component({
    selector: 'volatili',
    templateUrl: '/volatili.html' --> DOESN'T WORK
})
export class VolatiliComponent { }


// Pesci Us Component
@Component({
    selector: 'pesci',
    template: 'pesci.html' // WORKS
})
export class PesciComponent { }

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], 

    template: `    
    <nav>
      <ul>
              <li><a [routerLink]="['/Volatili']">VOLATILI</a></li>
              <li><a [routerLink]="['/Pesci']">PESCI</a></li>
              <li><a [routerLink]="['/Terrestri']">TERRESTRI</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,  
})

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/volatili', component: VolatiliComponent, as: 'Volatili' },
    { path: '/pesci', component: PesciComponent, as: 'Pesci' },
    { path: '/terrestri', component: TerrestriComponent, as: 'Terrestri' }
])

export class AppComponent {}
```

My file structure is:

```
-DEV 
   - app.component.ts
   - boot.ts
   - terrestri.html
   - volatili.html
   - pesci.html
```

I can't navigate to "volatili" which is defined in "templateURL" while I can go to "pesci" and "terrestri" successfully (they are defined in "template" and not "templateURL").

I've also tried with:

```
templateUrl: './volatili.html' --> DOESN'T WORK
templateUrl: 'volatili.html' --> DOESN'T WORK
```

Comment: Do you have the `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` tag (or in `bootstrap()`? Not sure, but I think it plays a role here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things:

```
template: '/terrestri.html', // WORKS, HOW?
```

**template** is meant for inline html like:

```
template: `<div></div>`
```

Probably you getting output like: `/terrestri.html`

Where your app is located? If you you place it in app directory ( for example ) then your templateUrl should be:

```
templateUrl: '/app/volatili.html'
```

Is DEV, in your example parent ( top ) directory? Try with:

```
templateUrl: '/DEV/volatili.html'
```